# Curl with ipv6 not working by default

Tags: ubuntu, http, ipv6, ubuntu-10.10, curl

I am trying to curl ipv6 adresses, but without success.

If i try lets say:

> curl https://google.com

I wait for a timeout and get `network unreachable`

If i force `ipv4`, everything is fine.

> curl -4 https://google.com

Then again if i force ipv6, like this:

> curl -6 https://google.com

i get:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2800:3f0:4001:806::1005: Network is unreachable

I suppose it has to do somehow with resolving `ipv6` adresses.

I saw that on other computers that have a newer version of some linux distro, these requests go fine, so i'm guessing it has to do something with me using `ubuntu 10.10`, where this problem isn't solved.

I want to be able to curl normally without using the option: `-4`, what do i have to modify to be able to use curl normally with `ipv6` adresses?

Comment: It sounds like you have [_broken_ IPv6 connectivity](http://test-ipv6.com/broken.html), so you need to figure out why it's broken. Start with some basic information such as `ip addr` and a description of your network and your ISP.

Comment: further answers can be found on this [duplicate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90742/45331). Regarding duplicate questions please take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/201151)

Comment: See my answer to the same question posted at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220149/43835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried connecting to other networks and it worked.

In the mean time i updated my OS to MINT v15 and the problem still stayed.

Actually it even got weirder cause i could `curl` once, everything would be okay, than i would do it the second time and it would present the same old error.

At last i called my ISP and they set my modem to factory settings and updated the software.

Now everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody finds this on Google like I did, to fix the issue I just had to tweak my firewall rules for IPv6.

By default I'd blocked everything on the incoming chain - after I added rules to allow established connections, ping requests and anything from localhost IPv6 connections started working!

Comment: This is not a solution. Share your settings